# AngularJS: Single Value variable in Controller or Service

Tags: angularjs

I am working with a SharePoint 2013 app and found out that SP365 doesn't support "joins." I have a large number of "feeder lists" and their corresponding ID saved in the main tables.

In a view I need to be able to call something like {{getVal(list, field, id)}} so that I can pass in let's say the id of a division {{getVal('division', 'title', currentProject.division)}} and it will return the value of "sales."

My question: should the function getVal be in the controllers controlling the form or in a service.

Right now, all of my service function are returning promises not single values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to call the function numerous places in the entire application, a service would be better. It also sounds like returning the value of sales is something independent that could be written on its own and used multiple places = service.